# Past perfect in past context

Tags: past-perfect, discourse-context

Could you please explain me why  past perfect in  this sentence? I think past simple can fit too?

Is it to emphasize the completion of the playing?

The reference time is now so play should be past simple

A year ago Rhodes had played just a handful of live shows. Now, 12 months later, he is something of a veteran, having supported Sam Smith, London Grammar, Laura Marling, Nick Mulvey and Rufus Wainwright.

Answer (score 3):

> A year ago Rhodes had played just a handful of live shows.

In this sentence reference time is not "now" but a point in the past, *a year ago*. At that point the *handful of live shows* already lay in the past; and past-in-past is expressed with the past perfect. Simple past, "A year ago Rhodes played a handful of shows" would mean that he played them **at** that time rather than **before** that time.

It is not until the second sentence that the reference time is equated with speech time, "now". **Now** he **is** (present) a veteran because he has supported many more artists.

Here's a timeline:

```
                            a year ago                           now
                            ↓                                    ↓
 ---------------------------+------------------------------------+-----------  
 ↑-- in this timespan he --↑   ↑--in this timespan he supports--↑
   plays a handful of live         Sam Smith, London Grammar, 
            shows                          and others
```

Comment: It is crystal clear now great answer